# Wrapping code when exporting to an image with Pygments

Tags: pygments

Reading through Pygments' formatters doc (https://pygments.org/docs/formatters/), I cannot find how to wrap long lines of code when using the ImageFormatter in order to export my highlighted code to a png image.

Here's my code:

```
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import ImageFormatter
from pygments import highlight

code = 'print("Reading through Pygments\' formatters doc (https://pygments.org/docs/formatters/), I cannot find how to wrap code when using the ImageFormatter in order to export my highlighted code to a png image (i.e. let\'s say I want my image to be 600px, or 300 characters at font size, wide). It seems like wrapping is essential when exporting to an image, is the option missing from Pygments at this moment?")'

formatter = ImageFormatter()
with open("highlighted1.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(highlight(code, PythonLexer(), formatter))
```

Which produces this image which (unusable for many applications):
[image]

It seems like wrapping is essential when exporting to an image, is the option missing from Pygments at this moment?

Answer (score 0):

The option to wrap lines is missing in the `pygments` library.

You could extend the `ImageFormatter` and override its `format` method to inserts new line tokens and wrap code lines.
The [`format` method](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/2.6.1/pygments/__init__.py#L63) is passed a list of tokens.

Focus on doing this procedure on `Token.Literal.String.Double` tokens to be more precise.

Otherwise, format `code` before it is passed in the `highlight` function properly.
You can do that manually or programatically using a linter. Most linters do not fix long strings.

For example with [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/), has bearly any effect on code

```
import autopep8

autopep8.fix_code(code, options=autopep8.parse_args(['']))
```

`code` has to be manually written as:

```
code = """ 
    print( 
        "Reading through Pygments' formatters doc(https://pygments.org/docs/formatters/), " 
        "I cannot find how to wrap code when using the ImageFormatter in order to export my " 
        "highlighted code to a png image (i.e. let's say I want my image to be 600px, " 
        "or 300 characters at font size, wide). It seems like wrapping is essential " 
        "when exporting to an image, is the option missing from Pygments at this moment?" 
    ) 
"""
```